# TclError: No more menus can be allocated

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl

So I'm making a program in Python and for user interface I'm using Tkinter, the application seems to be running fine but as I navigate a while in it, I get the follwing TclError:

```
TclError: No more menus can be allocated.
```

I did some research and I found out that there is a limit for these "menus" on windows, but my question is, how do I know that these menus are being created? How can I delete them when I stop using them? I use methods for deleting top menus as "top.destroy()". But even though I am generating more and more menus and it's overflowing the windows heap or whatever it is.

Here is the source code for my program:
https://github.com/molBR/upgestao
Can somebody help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you generating more and more menus? I can't imagine a program needing more than a dozen or two in a worst case scenario. Can you create a [mcve] that shows us how you are creating an absurdly large number of menus? Please don't link to code on an external site. Take the time to reduce it down to something small, and include it directly in your question.

Comment: put code in question

Comment: Just how many option-menus are you really using?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error when creating auto-hide menu. At first I created automatically generated and deleted dummy (empty) menu bar to replace a real menu bar to hide it. So after several dozens hiding `tkinter` start to show me this error: `TclError: No more menus can be allocated.`

The solution is simple: do not create/delete menus automatically.

Just create all necessary menus you want and save them in the memory. Do not delete them. And switch between menus during work of your program.